# Implementing fold in simple purely functional language without lazy evaluation

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation, fold

I am trying to implement a simple functional language for automatic program synthesis.
The data structure is a graph of functions and values, which compiles down to javascript.
The following graph should be a fold function.  `funcApp` nodes are connected to a function node and a number of value nodes, and it applies the function to the values.  `arg0` is the list, `arg1` is an initial value (z) `arg2` is the function to be applied.

[image]

It is equivalent to the folloiwng scheme definition (although my 'language' is not Scheme, it is the graph)

```
(define (foldr f z xs)
   (if (null? xs)
       z
       (f (car xs) (foldr f z (cdr xs)))))
```

The problem is that there are since there are no special operators, everything, in particular `if` is just a normal function.  In this form, the program never terminates and instead reaches the maximum stack depth, since the else clause is always computed.

I presume this problem is solved in some languages by lazy evaluation.  So my questions are: is there functional version of fold that will not have this infinite recursion 2) where to begin thinking about applying lazy evaluation to a simple language such as this, if necessary.

Comment: `if` is a special form in Scheme, so the else expression is *not* always evaluated. What's the question here?

Comment: I know that is the case for Scheme, and I think I stated my questions quite explicitly in the last paragraph

Comment: I don't understand the first question. The answer to 2) would be "handle `if` specially".

Comment: "is there functional version of fold that will not have this infinite recursion" Am I just stupid or does this have *nothing* to do with lazy evaluation / strict vs. non-strict?

Comment: @sepp2k: I don't think that's true. You could use this `if` to select a lambda or something and call it afterwards. Agreed though that this has nothing to do with `fold`.

Comment: @NiklasB. You're right, of course. It would be true in a language without first-class functions though.

Comment: Well as you have indicated to me, perhaps lazy evaluation has nothing to do with fold, is that sufficient reason to vote to close this?  I am new to functional programming and don't have all the answers, hence why I am asking questions.

Comment: @zenna: It's not a problem that you don't know the answers to your own questions, of course :) It's just that from your post its hard to tell what you actually want to know or what your problem is.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't see where the confusion about what I am asking comes from.  I wanted to know how to implement a version of fold which would avoid this problem I was having due to the else clause always being computed, which I (perhaps erroneously) put down to the lack of lazy evaluation.  A legitimate answer, which is what I think is being said by the two of you, is that a fold is impossible without treating if specially or having non strict evaluation order.  I don't see how this makes the question wrong or unclear.

Comment: @zenna: First of all, non-strict is not the same as lazy. Second, Scheme solves this by just handling `if` differently than other function calls (this is called a special form). You don't need full-blown lazy evaluation for that, like Haskell has (although you could implement `if-then-else` as a simple function in Haskell). The statement by sepp that you can't write `fold` if you don't have a lazy `if` was not quite correct (and he deleted that comment already): You can emulate the behaviour by supplying lambdas to the `if` and calling the result.

Comment: BTW, my confusion mainly came from the fact that you were presenting a "Scheme" example that is in fact not Scheme :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks, I can see how scheme snippet was confusing.  Actually that is Scheme, and I am not doing anything scheme based at all, I used it as an example only to show the exact function I am trying to implement.   Perhaps I should clarify that.

Comment: Racket accepts the definition just fine.

Comment: Something to consider: while `if` has been implemented as a strict function before (e.g., in Excel formulas), it is very much more popular to provide a special case conditional construct that is lazy (only evaluates / executes the choice taken).  Depending on what you're doing, having a strict `if` may not be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's pretty uncommon to evaluate under binders (and, in particular, to evaluate the body of lambdas), so I think the standard solution to lazifying a strict language is to introduce a lambda. I don't know the scheme syntax, but in Haskell syntax, if you wanted `x` to be a lazy parameter to a strict function `f`, you might write something like `f (\() -> x)` (and modify `f` appropriately to expect such lambdas, and call them at the moment you want to un-lazy them).

Comment: Scheme syntax would be fairly similar to the Haskell syntax, `(λ () x)` is a thunk, and surrounding a thunk in parens "calls" it, e.g. `(someThunk)`

Answer (score 1):

You could compile both branches of an if-expression into thunks, and call the appropriate thunk based on the condition.  It wouldn't surprise me if the formal definition of scheme is written that way.